# how to display data from graphql query Gatsbyjs?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I need some help here. I am using Gatsbyjs and contentful. I have queried the data using graphql. I can see the object but i can't seem to display it in a div. What am I missing here ? The error keeps saying can't read undefined properties of map. Is there another way of doing this ? The content includes text, image and an mp3. Let me know what I am missing here.

This is the code

```
const IndexPage = ({data}) => {
  
  console.log(data);
  
  return (
    <div>
    {data.edges.map(edge => <p key={edge} >{edge}</p>)}
    </div>
      )
}

export const query = graphql `
query MyQuery {
  allContentfulPodcast {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        thumbnail {
          file {
            details {
              image {
                height
                width
              }
              size
            }
            fileName
            url
          }
        }
        video {
          file {
            fileName
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

console log object

```
{
    "allContentfulPodcast": {
        "edges": [
            {
                "node": {
                    "title": "Welcome to our show",
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "file": {
                            "details": {
                                "image": {
                                    "height": 5304,
                                    "width": 7952
                                },
                                "size": 4752704
                            },
                            "fileName": "business.jpg",
                            "url": "//images.ctfassets.net/hi3b2mc578jm/3wxzzKv4Rblsv1FAUR2SQ/d8f09ade7e9fc57afa2f425bb2da9ed5/business.jpg"
                        }
                    },
                    "video": {
                        "file": {
                            "fileName": "watch",
                            "url": "//assets.ctfassets.net/hi3b2mc578jm/4kK38bwyJRxPYoM3SADQrU/4b11d4079052f651685a407c7fc6ecb4/watch"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the console.log(data) results please

Comment: just added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to pass some value to `<p>` tag instead of the whole object.
For example:

```
<div>
  {data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.map((edge, index) => <p key={index}>{edge.node.title}</p>)}
</div>
```

Comment: tried that before - same issue" Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: @shar27 just edited. I forgot about `allContentfulPodcast`

Comment: yes, this was correct. I forgot the node.title. Thank you. Would it be similar for querying images and audio ?

Comment: yes. but instead of `<p>` tag you have to provide the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing another level of your object: "can't read undefined properties of map" you should try:

```
  return (
    <div>
      {data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.map(edge => <p key={edge.node.title} >{edge}</p>)}
    </div>
    )
```

Comment: tried that before too, it gave me this Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {node}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: updated, another level issue - the field you want to render has to be a value and not an object so change to edge.node.title in the p tag